# Use Spring Security with JDBC backend

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I have followed the steps in this chapter of a Spring Security tutorial:

[Go to tutorial on spring.io](https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/03/sso-with-oauth2-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-v)

I have built an app that works perfectly:

[image]

Then I wanted to implement a JDBC backend as described in this example:

[Go to example on GitHub](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/tree/master/tests/annotation/jdbc)

I changed the initial project as shown in the example app on GitHub:

[image]

Now **it seems that the Resource Server is not able to check tokens** any more at the `/uaa/user` endpoint:

**Executed commands:**

[image]

**Logs from the OAuth2 Authorization Server**

```
2016-02-28 12:35:08.762  INFO 1029 --- [nio-9999-exec-3] o.s.s.o.p.token.store.JdbcTokenStore     : Failed to find access token for token 41b1504d-b985-40e0-80a8-94c09992aafe
2016-02-28 12:37:58.604  INFO 1029 --- [nio-9999-exec-7] o.s.s.o.p.token.store.JdbcTokenStore     : Failed to find access token for token 41b1504d-b985-40e0-80a8-94c09992aafe
2016-02-28 12:44:06.845  INFO 1029 --- [nio-9999-exec-6] o.s.s.o.p.token.store.JdbcTokenStore     : Failed to find access token for token 41b1504d-b985-40e0-80a8-94c09992aafe
```

**Logs from the Resource Server**

```
2016-02-28 12:37:42.149  INFO 1186 --- [0.1-8181-exec-3] o.s.b.a.s.o.r.UserInfoTokenServices      : Getting user info from: http://localhost:9999/uaa/user
2016-02-28 12:37:42.228  INFO 1186 --- [0.1-8181-exec-3] o.s.b.a.s.o.r.UserInfoTokenServices      : Could not fetch user details: class org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.resource.UserRedirectRequiredException, A redirect is required to get the users approval
2016-02-28 12:37:58.600  INFO 1186 --- [0.1-8181-exec-5] o.s.b.a.s.o.r.UserInfoTokenServices      : Getting user info from: http://localhost:9999/uaa/user
2016-02-28 12:37:58.623  INFO 1186 --- [0.1-8181-exec-5] o.s.b.a.s.o.r.UserInfoTokenServices      : Could not fetch user details: class java.lang.IllegalArgumentException, URI is not absolute
2016-02-28 12:44:06.839  INFO 1186 --- [0.1-8181-exec-7] o.s.b.a.s.o.r.UserInfoTokenServices      : Getting user info from: http://localhost:9999/uaa/user
2016-02-28 12:44:06.848  INFO 1186 --- [0.1-8181-exec-7] o.s.b.a.s.o.r.UserInfoTokenServices      : Could not fetch user details: class org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.exceptions.InvalidRequestException, Possible CSRF detected - state parameter was present but no state could be found
```

Here are the important classes:

**OAuth2 Authorization Server: SaAuthApplication.class**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@RestController
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class SaAuthApplication {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @RequestMapping("/user")
    public Principal user(Principal user) {
        return user;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SaAuthApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    protected static class ResourceServer extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private TokenStore tokenStore;

        @Override
        public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources)
                throws Exception {
            resources.tokenStore(tokenStore);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
        }

    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    protected static class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private AuthenticationManager auth;

        @Autowired
        private DataSource dataSource;

        private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();

        @Bean
        public JdbcTokenStore tokenStore() {
            return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
        }

        @Bean
        protected AuthorizationCodeServices authorizationCodeServices() {
            return new JdbcAuthorizationCodeServices(dataSource);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security)
                throws Exception {
            security.passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
                throws Exception {
            endpoints.authorizationCodeServices(authorizationCodeServices())
                    .authenticationManager(auth).tokenStore(tokenStore())
                    .approvalStoreDisabled();
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            clients.jdbc(dataSource)
                    .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder)
                .withClient("my-trusted-client")
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code",
                            "refresh_token", "implicit")
                    .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT", "ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT")
                    .scopes("read", "write", "trust")
                    .resourceIds("oauth2-resource")
                    .accessTokenValiditySeconds(60).and()
                .withClient("my-client-with-registered-redirect")
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code")
                    .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT").scopes("read", "trust")
                    .resourceIds("oauth2-resource")
                    .redirectUris("http://anywhere?key=value").and()
                .withClient("my-client-with-secret")
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("client_credentials", "password")
                    .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT").scopes("read")
                    .resourceIds("oauth2-resource").secret("secret");
            // @formatter:on
        }

    }

    @Autowired
    public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
            auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource).withUser("dave")
                    .password("secret").roles("USER");
            // @formatter:on
    }

}
```

**Resource Server: application.yml**

```
security:
  oauth2:
    resource:
      user-info-uri: http://localhost:9999/uaa/user
```

**Resource Server: SaEmployeeApplication.class**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableResourceServer
public class SaEmployeeApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SaEmployeeApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Everything works fine at the **OAuth2 Authorization Server**. I can authorize clients and get tokens back. But the **Resource Server** seems to be unable to check the token at the `/uaa/user` endpoint.

Comment: why you have two `@EnableResourceServer` annotation? try to remove one from `SaEmployeeApplication` class

Comment: @MangEngkus it does not work. If I try to access the Resource Server after removing the `@EnableResourceServer` I get the following log (after obtaining a new token of course): `{"timestamp":1456737185144,"status":401,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"Full authentication is required to access this resource","path":"/api/employees/employees"}`

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my own question:

The `expires_in` value of the token was only 59 seconds. So there simply was not enough time to setup the request.

The `.accessTokenValiditySeconds(60)` sets the `expires_in` value.

[Read more](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/703)